# kdeconnect on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: xubuntu, kde-connect

Has anybody tried `kdeconnect` on **Xubuntu 20.04** with satisfactory results?

I installed and used it and the results were extremely disappointing. The files I transferred from the phone were completely corrupted. 100% failure.
The same files get transferred with `kdeconnect` on **Kubuntu 18.04** 100% successfully. Since `kdeconnect` developers say that the app is fully compatible and functional on all desktop environments, why is this happening I wonder?!

Answer (score 0):

Check for `firewalld` and `ufw` if are installed could blocking required ports listed here: https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect

Comment: The connections are ok. I can even move the computer's mouse pointer by moving my finger on the phone surface. The file transfers are also made. The copy on the computer though is not the same as the prototype on the phone.